# Find pairs in an integer array whose sum == 10

Tags: java, unit-testing, interview-questions

I'm practicing for technical interviews and I'm looking for ways to improve my answers/code. Please point out the flaws you see and how I can make this better.

Task:
Find pairs in an integer array whose sum is equal to 10
(bonus: do it in linear time)

#### Pairs.java

```
  //Container class that will hold the indices of the pairs found

    public class Pairs<T,K> {

        private T tval;
        private K kval;

        public Pairs(){

        }

        public Pairs(T tv, K kv){

            this.tval = tv;
            this.kval = kv;

        }

        public T getFirst() {

            return tval;

        }

        public void setFirst(T tval) {

            this.tval = tval;

        }

        public K getSecond() {

            return kval;

        }

        public void setSecond(K kval) {

            this.kval = kval;

        }

        public void clear(){

            this.tval = null;
            this.kval = null;

        }

    }
```

#### EqualPairs.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import Utilities.Pairs;

    /**
     * Find pairs in an integer array whose sum is equal to 10
     * (bonus: do it in linear time)   
     * 
     */

    public class EqualPairs {

        //O(n^2). First solution I came up with. Debugging through this
        //method actually gave me the idea on how to attempt to solve this
        //problem in linear time.
        public static ArrayList<Pairs> equal(int[] array){

            int numComparisons = 0; //for big O analysis
            ArrayList<Pairs> pairsList = new ArrayList<Pairs>();
            for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
                    if(array[i]+array[j]==10 && i!=j && i<j){
                        Pairs pair = new Pairs(i,j);
                        pairsList.add(pair);    
                    }
                    numComparisons++;
                }
            }
            log("Number of comparisons made for input of size "+array.length+": "+numComparisons);
            return pairsList;
        }

        public static void log(Object o){

            System.out.println(o);

        }

        //Asymptotic complexity unknown
        public static ArrayList<Pairs> equalInLinear(int[] array){

            int numComparisons = 0; //for big O Analysis
            ArrayList<Pairs> pairsList = new ArrayList<Pairs>();
            for(int i = 0;i<array.length;i++){
                //j=i+1 is the only difference between this method and
                //the previous one. 
                for(int j=i+1;j<array.length;j++){
                    if(array[i]+array[j]==10 && i!=j && i<j){
                        Pairs pair = new Pairs(i,j);
                        pairsList.add(pair);    
                    }
                    numComparisons++;
                }
            }
            log("Number of comparisons made for input of size "+array.length+": "+numComparisons);
            return pairsList;
        }
    }
```

#### EqualPairsTest.java

```
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import Utilities.Pairs;
    import junit.framework.TestCase;

    public class EqualPairsTest extends TestCase {
        @Test
        public void testEqualSimpleOne() {

            int[] arr1={1,9};
            ArrayList<Pairs> p =EqualPairs.equal(arr1);

            assertEquals(1,p.get(0).getSecond());
            assertEquals(0,p.get(0).getFirst());
        }

        public void testEqualSimpleTwo(){

            int[] arr={3,5,6,7,5,-1,11};
            ArrayList<Pairs> p = EqualPairs.equal(arr);

            assertEquals(0, p.get(0).getFirst()); 
            assertEquals(3,p.get(0).getSecond());  

            assertEquals(1, p.get(1).getFirst());   
            assertEquals(4, p.get(1).getSecond()); 

            assertEquals(5, p.get(2).getFirst()); 
            assertEquals(6, p.get(2).getSecond());      
        }

        public void testEqualLinearSimple(){

            int[] arr1={1,9};
            ArrayList<Pairs> p =EqualPairs.equalInLinear(arr1);

            assertEquals(1,p.get(0).getSecond());
            assertEquals(0,p.get(0).getFirst());
        }

        public void testEqualInLinearSimpleTwo(){

            int[] arr={3,5,6,7,5,-1,11};
            ArrayList<Pairs> p = EqualPairs.equalInLinear(arr);

            assertEquals(0, p.get(0).getFirst()); 
            assertEquals(3,p.get(0).getSecond());  

            assertEquals(1, p.get(1).getFirst());   
            assertEquals(4, p.get(1).getSecond()); 

            assertEquals(5, p.get(2).getFirst()); 
            assertEquals(6, p.get(2).getSecond()); 

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### \$O(n^2)\$, not linear

The second algorithm is superior to the first, but is still an \$O(n^2)\$ algorithm.  Furthermore, you have some redundant checks.  This:

> ```
>                if(array[i]+array[j]==10 && i!=j && i<j){
> ```

could be turned into this:

```
                if (array[i] + array[j] == 10) {
```

because `j` starts at `i+1` so you know the last two conditions are always true.

### Faster methods

One faster method would be to sort the array first.  Then you can locate the pairs in linear time after that.  This would be \$O(nlog(n))\$ total time.  However, depending on how duplicates are handled, this could also degenerate to \$O(n^2)\$ time (for example an array of all 5's).

An even faster method would be to use a HashMap to store each value that you have seen so far.  Then when you come across a new value such as 7, you use the HashMap to look up whether you have seen a 3 so far.  If you have, then 7/3 is a valid pairing.  This will run in \$O(n)\$ time if duplicates are not printed.

Keep in mind that if all duplicate pairs must be printed, no solution will do better than \$O(n^2)\$, because you will need to print every pair if the array consists of all 5's.